# asp.net core - modelstate badrequest inconsistent behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core

I have a simple model:

```
public class Item : Entity<int>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Inside controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Item item)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
       return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    repository.Create(item);
    await repository.SaveAsync();
    return Created($"/api/v1/items/{item.Id}", new { message = "Item was created successfully!" });
}
```

Now, for following three incorrect sample inputs I get following responses:

Sample #1:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1/items
content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "sample1",
    "cost": $100000
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "cost": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ]
}
```

Sample #2:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1/items
content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "sample2",
    "cost": "10000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "cost": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ]
}
```

Sample #3:  **This one seems like a bug. An empty key appears (instead of int out of range error)**

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1/items
content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "sample3",
    "cost": 10000000000000000000000000
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ],
  "cost": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ]
}
```

**Edit:**
Added a tracking ticket on github - https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5672

Answer (score 1):

First and last are invalid json and the second one has too high number for the integer `cost`. Make sure your cost does not exceed `INT_MAX: 2147483647`.

Comment: I know that, but why the error shows an extra property with no key

Comment: Missread your question, sorry. My guess is that it finds the last opening `"` and thinks it starts a new value. Since there is no name defined it outputs it as empty and invalid. It appears to be a bug as it should not consider this `"` for a new value and rather part of `cost` as its before the `,`. I would report it on github https://github.com/aspnet/Home